# How to create custome Animation for hide panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have some panel in page (Like Visual studio), i Want when user click in Button hide this Panel hide with animation like visual studio[image]
when user click on + icon toolbox with animation go to left side and hide. i want design this animation. thanks for help me.

Comment: Try searching google instead of posting your problem on stackoverflow. A number of options are available on first page of google search result.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @  Arvind07: i very search in google but not found slotion for this problem. thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](http://aext.net/example/slide-panel-jquery/)?

Comment: @  Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: thanks for help me. this soloution is good. but how to select this comment for answare ok???

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something [like this](http://aext.net/example/slide-panel-jquery/)?